# Call multiple url with Http request

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, https

I have the following code.If my `url[0]` is down/had any issue i.e !200 then i need to call another url
`url[1]`.how can i code it effeciently.I am using spring boot and java 8.

```
url[0] = server1.8080/get/data
url[1] = server2.8080/get/data

ResponseEntity<MyPojo> response  =restTemplate().exchange(url[0],HttpMethod.GET, request, MyPojo.class)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Ribbon for client side load balancing with ribbon.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-ribbon.html

There are a few steps to make it work:

1. add the ribbon dependency to your pom.xml
2. configure the servers in the application.properties or
   application.yaml.
3. Configure the Ribbon Client

Please find a complete tutorial here:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-rest-client-with-netflix-ribbon

Comment: Ok.. wil ahve a look at it.right now i am using IF/ELSE to solve my problem